# break one DF row to multiple row in another DF

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am looking to convert one DF into another.
the difference is 1 row in DF1 may be 3 rows in DF2
example DF1

```
cust_id | email_id_1 | email_id_2 | email_id_3 |
1       |one_1@m.com | one_2@m.com| one_3@m.com|
```

then DF2 will be like

```
cust_id | email_id   | 
1       |one_1@m.com | 
1       |one_2@m.com |
1       |one_3@m.com |
```

I have written below code , which is giving me error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'cast'

```
# Create a schema for the dataframe
dfSchema = StructType([
    StructField('CUST_ID', LongType()),
    StructField('EMAIL_ADDRESS', StringType())
    ])
dfData = []


for row in initialCustEmailDetailsDF.rdd.collect():
    if row["email_address_1"]!="":
        temp1 = [row["cust_id"].cast(LongType()),row["email_address_1"]]
        # error : AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'cast'
        dfData.append(temp1)
    if row["email_address_2"]!="":
        temp2 = [row["cust_id"].cast(LongType()),row["email_address_2"]]
        dfData.append(temp2)
    if row["email_address_3"]!="":
        temp3 = [row["cust_id"].cast(LongType())row["email_address_3"]]
        dfData.append(temp3)

# Convert list to RDD
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(dfData)

# Create data frame
df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, dfSchema)
df.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for `explode_outer`:

```
df.show()
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|cust_id| email_id_1| email_id_2| email_id_3|
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|      1|one_1@m.com|one_2@m.com|       null|
|      2|one_1@m.com|       null|one_3@m.com|
|      3|one_1@m.com|one_2@m.com|one_3@m.com|
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+

import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df2 = df.select(
    'cust_id',
    F.explode_outer(
        F.array('email_id_1', 'email_id_2', 'email_id_3')
    ).alias('email_id')
)

df2.show()
+-------+-----------+
|cust_id|   email_id|
+-------+-----------+
|      1|one_1@m.com|
|      1|one_2@m.com|
|      1|       null|
|      2|one_1@m.com|
|      2|       null|
|      2|one_3@m.com|
|      3|one_1@m.com|
|      3|one_2@m.com|
|      3|one_3@m.com|
+-------+-----------+
```

Comment: doesnt work... 
|cust_id| email_address_1   |    email_address_2 |    email_address_3 |
| 1     |     FIRST@AOL.COM |     FIRST_2@AOL.COM|                null|
| 3     |  THIRD@COMCAST.NET|  THIRD_2@COMCAST.NET|  THIRD_3@COMCAST.NET|



+-------+--------------------+
|cust_id|            email_id|
+-------+--------------------+
|      1|       FIRST@AOL.COM|
|      1|       FIRST@AOL.COM|
|      1|                null|
|      3|   THIRD@COMCAST.NET|
|      3|   THIRD@COMCAST.NET|
|      3| THIRD_3@COMCAST.NET|

Comment: unable to share formatted text in comments so uploaded a formatted image... https://otbstuff.blogspot.com/2020/12/sample.html , for starters see cust_id=3 ... then corner cases like cust_id=1 & 2

Comment: thanks for your quick replt , tried both explode and explode_outer , i see same output

Comment: thanks for detailed answer , i had a typo in my code.... can you help me handle null ? if null i dont want any row...

Comment: @Lav just do `df3 = df2.dropna(subset = ['email_id'])`